# R: Perform a T-Test across all matching rows of two different dataframes

Tags: arrays, r, statistics

So, in excel, there is a formula ttest which can perform a ttest across a given row (using TWO DIFFERENT ARRAYS, e.g. =TTEST(A1:L1, M1:Z1,2,2) - in this case, two-tailed, type 2). It returns a pvalue for that row.

I would like to know if there is an analogous way to do this in R, where I have two dataframe (df1 and df2) of equal length which represent the two arrays, and the new vector returns the result of the t test for each row.

So, the T-test would take all the row1 values in df1 as the first array, and all the row1 values in df2 as the second array, return a pvalue for that row in the new ttest vector, and continue down to the last row.

Thank you for your kind help.

Note: I do not necessarily know the number of columns in each dataframe, and they will vary every time I run it. That's why I want to automate it.

Comment: So, just as a follow up, I tried to remedy the situation using the following loop:

p <- numeric(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(df1)))
    p[i] <- t.test(df1[i],df2[i], var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
BUT I am getting the following error: Error in [.data.frame(df1, i) : undefined columns selected Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is with a `for` loop as in:

```
p <- numeric(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(df1)))
    pvalues[i] <- t.test(df1[i],df2[i])$p.value
```

you should be warned that taking rows out of a data.frame often causes some confusing type coercion, so I would convert the data.frames to a matrix first and test that the matrix is numeric as in

```
mx1 <- as.matrix(df1)
stopifnot(inherits(mx1,c('integer','numeric')))
```

and us mx1 in place of df1 in the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi @Jthorpe, I am getting the following error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, i) : undefined columns selected. Do you know how to fix this?